# Selenium Python desired capabilities cannot create a new driver instance

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Desired Capabilities in Selenium Python for IE on our 64bit machine, Windows 2008 as IEDriverServer.exe keeps crashing half way through the test when i use:

```
cls.driver = webdriver.Ie(Globals.IEdriver_path)
```

I want try Desired Capabilities, see if it works ok this way.

I have the following in my setup:

```
    class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platform'] = 'WINDOWS'
    desired_caps['browserName'] = 'INTERNETEXPLORER'
    #cls.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://192.168.1.103:4444/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    cls.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    cls.driver = webdriver.Ie(Globals.IEdriver_path)
    cls.driver.get(Globals.URL)
    cls.login_page = login.LoginPage(cls.driver)
```

I run the Selenium Server jar file as follows:

```
    java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
```

When i run my Selenium Python test i get the following error:

```
  WebDriverException: Message: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browserName=INTERNETEXPLORER, platform=WINDOWS}]
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'JUSTIN-PC', ip: '192.168.1.164', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance (DefaultDriverFactory.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (None:-1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)
```

If i use:

```
cls.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://192.168.1.103:4444/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Then I will get the following error:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

How should i set Desired Capabilities in Selenium Python?

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to start a remote session with Internet Explorer:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
capabilities.update({'logLevel' : 'ERROR'})
remote_server = "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"

driver = webdriver.Remote(remote_server, capabilities)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: Do you know if I set a trace log for the IEDriverServer.exe in the capabilties?

Comment: Have a look here for the capabilities: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver